# Get count of unique widgets on a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

Consider an SQL which retrieves widgets by category:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  widgets w 
  JOIN categories c USING (widget_id) 
WHERE c.category IN ('print', 'automotive', 'beer') 
  AND w.stock > 0 ;
```

If a widget appears in two categories, then will appear twice in the listing. **How can I return a count of widgets without dupes due to appearing in multiple categories?**

Note that the following query returns the correct count, however it requires building a temporary table in memory, which is not feasible on large databases:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        w.widget_id 
    FROM
        widgets w 
        JOIN categories c USING (widget_id) 
    WHERE c.category IN ('print', 'automotive', 'beer') 
      AND w.stock > 0
) foo;
```

**Can a query which returns the same result be concocted which does not require the temporary table?**

Comment: select count(Distinct widget_id) directly

Comment: @dagfr: Thank you, that works! Since you beat the answer which basically states the same thing, please post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: I just posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use SELECT COUNT(Distinct widget_id)

```
SELECT 
COUNT(Distinct widget_id) 
FROM
    widgets w 
JOIN categories c USING (widget_id) 
WHERE c.category IN ('print', 'automotive', 'beer') 
    AND w.stock > 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @dagfr said:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(Distinct widget_id) 
FROM
  widgets w 
  JOIN categories c USING (widget_id) 
WHERE c.category IN ('print', 'automotive', 'beer') 
  AND w.stock > 0 ;
```

This way you are going to count the widget only once.

Comment: Thank you Peter. +1, but I'll let dagfr post this as an answer to accept though.